# designer workflow

Tags: workflow, workflowservicefrontend

can we open sharepoint workflows in sharepoint designer ?i was asked this question in interview , I said yes but frankly speaking I have doubt on the question itself .Can someone explain me?

Comment: Which workflows you are talking about? We have SharePoint Designer workflows, Custom workflows, nintex workflows, K2 workflows in SharePoint.

Comment: Interview questions are not supposed to be asked here. try this forum http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.. To answer your question, if workflow is created in designer. then yes.. you can edit it.. but not the workflow created in Visual studio

Comment: 1.what is list,reusable,site workflow?also 3state ,approval,feedback,signature

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is SharePoint workflows can only be opened with SharePoint Designer if the workflow was originally built with SharePoint Designer. This applies to both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 platform workflows.#

Those workflows that are not built in SharePoint Designer, such as those built with Visual Studio, Nintex, K2, etc. - although most of these workflow solutions are built on top of SharePoint's built-in workflow platform - can not be opened and changed in SharePoint Designer.